# How to autoincrement the AJAX url page number on per click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am implementing a function that is pulling Pokemon Card data per page. My main issue I am trying to solve, is getting my AJAX function to update the url pageCnt variable, for every click, akin to a Next button.

```js
var pageCnt = 25;
function getPokeResults() {

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://api.pokemontcg.io/v1/cards?nationalPokedexNumber=" + pageCnt,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        async: true,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data, status, jqXHR) {
            $("#output").html();
            for (var i = 0; i < data.cards.length; i++) {
                // console.table(data.cards[i]);
                $("#output").prepend("<div>" + data.cards[i].name + "<img src=" + "data.cards[i].imageUrl" + "/>" + "</div>");
            }
                            /// This is adding a +1 per click as I want, but the AJAX URL keeps loading the page from nationalPokedexNumber  25, as the pageCnt
                pageCnt++;

                alert(pageCnt);
        }
    })
}



$(document).ready(function() {
/*
Automatically load the first set
 */
    getPokeResults();
/*
When the searchBtn is clicked, we want to increment the URL value per +1 eachtime
 */
    $("#searchBtn").click(function() {
        getPokeResults();
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Poke Card Results</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="output"> </div>
  <div class="container">
    <!-- <input type="text" id="pageCnt" /> -->
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="searchBtn"> Submit</button>

    <!-- <button class="btn btn-primary" id="pageincreaseCount"> Increase Count</button> -->


  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I implemented a pageCnt++ that seems to increment the value, however it does not seem to be reflected in the URL,when I click on the "searchBtn"

All the data I want seems to be pulled in.

Comment: the code you provided runs fine even in `run code snippet` button , i checked with chrome inspector and the pageCnt variable increases correct

Comment: @gijoe I am a fool. Was having another look at home, and seems to be working now. Not sure if I did something, or was overworking myself. Thanks for having a look, though, would +1 you if I could. :)